# QML ChartView: Crash on object destruction when assigend "series" has set an "id"

Tags: qt, memory, qml, destructor, qtcharts

When I delete a QML Object that contains a ChartView, everything works fine. The moment when I assign the "series" of the chart an ID, the destruction crashes.

Works fine:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ChartView {
        width: 450
        height: 450

        PieSeries {
            PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
            PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
        }
    }
}
```

Crashes (see "id: testId in PieSeries):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ChartView {

        width: 450
        height: 450

        PieSeries {
            id: testId
            PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
            PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
        }
    }
}
```

just start/quit the program, and it will not exit correctly due to the crash on destruction. This happens with any ChartView / Series combination.

> Starting
>   build-ChartTest-Desktop_Qt_5_9_2_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\ChartTest.exe...
>   QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment. The
>   program has unexpectedly finished. The process was ended forcefully.

stacktrace:

> 7 QtCharts::DeclarativePieSeries::~DeclarativePieSeries |
>   qtchartsqml2d
>
> 8
>   QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement::~QQmlElement
>   | qqmlprivate.h
>
> 9 QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement::`scalar
>   deleting destructor' | qtchartsqml2d
>
> 10 QV4::QObjectWrapper::destroyObject qv4qobjectwrapper.cpp
>
> 11 QV4::MemoryManager::sweep | qv4mm.cpp
>
> 12 QV4::MemoryManager::~MemoryManager | qv4mm.cpp
>
> 13 QV4::MemoryManager::`scalar deleting destructor' | Qt5Qmld
>
> 14 QV4::ExecutionEngine::~ExecutionEngine | qv4engine.cpp
>
> 15 QV4::ExecutionEngine::`scalar deleting destructor' | Qt5Qmld

Comment: I've tested in 5.9.0 and this code works for me w/o problem. Windows 10/ Qt 5.9.0/MinGW

Comment: Tested with 5.9.2 and MinGW it works. But with MSVC2017, just having the ChartView (no series) will make the app crash when opening the window.

Comment: @gekko42 You should report your bug on https://bugreports.qt.io I will also report mine with MSVC2017, I am not sure they are related.

Comment: I will test with MinGW later, i'm on W10 / 5.9.2 / MSVC2015

Comment: It seems to be fixed in 5.10 beta. I'll run some test with the 5.9.3 branch later today. Are you using 32bit or 64 bit MSVC 2015 ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm using MSVC2015 64bit

Comment: I just tested, with MinGW it also works fine for me.